# How to set summernote set image to take full width always

Tags: javascript, html, css, summernote

I am working with a project that uses Summernote WYSIWYG plugin. For images that we upload with the editor, I need to set the image width to take full width(100%) by default. so that there will be no text wrapping or arranging issues with the text. It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

here is the form element and script that I use summernote.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Post body</label>
<textarea name="body" id="postBody" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#postBody').summernote({height: 300,});
});
```

Comment: What if the image is thumbnail sized?

Comment: @AdityaThakur: didn't get you. can you please elaborate more

Comment: i mean if the images are quite small, will it be stretched to fit the summernote width? or there will text wrapping around it?

Comment: the requirement is to set any images to full width. regardless of the size. I don't know why the client needs that. but it is the requirement.

Comment: can you paste the code you've so far?

Comment: @AdityaThakur:added the code.

Comment: are you planning to upload the image to server as ajax?

Comment: @AdityaThakur: found out a solution mate. I will post it as an answer. It worked for me when uploading images but not when adding images as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a callback as follows. and it worked for me when uploading images. but not when adding images as a link.

```
callbacks: {
   onImageUpload: function (files) {

                        if (!files.length) return;
                        var file = files[0];
                        // create FileReader
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function () {
                            // when loaded file, img's src set datauri
                            console.log("img", $("<img>"));
                            var img = $("<img>").attr({src: reader.result, width: "100%"}); // << Add here img attributes !
                            console.log("var img", img);
                            $('#postBody').summernote("insertNode", img[0]);
                        }

                        if (file) {
                            // convert fileObject to datauri
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: I had issues making the above code to work. When I added reader.readAsDataURL(file);  before reader.onloadend  function, it helped.

Makes sense to me, Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still a problem, but I solved it by adjusting the summernote.js

in the "Editor.prototype.insertImage" function I changed one line. See below.

```
Original:
Editor.prototype.insertImage = function (src, param) {
    var _this = this;
    return createImage(src, param).then(function ($image) {
        _this.beforeCommand();
        if (typeof param === 'function') {
            param($image);
        }
        else {
            if (typeof param === 'string') {
                $image.attr('data-filename', param);
            }
            $image.css('width', Math.min(_this.$editable.width(), $image.width()));
        }
        $image.show();
        range.create(_this.editable).insertNode($image[0]);
        range.createFromNodeAfter($image[0]).select();
        _this.afterCommand();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        _this.context.triggerEvent('image.upload.error', e);
    });
};
```

Make following change

`$image.css('width', Math.min(_this.$editable.width(), $image.width()));`

change above line in summernote.js to

`$image.css('width', '100%');`

And new inserted images will have width=100% per default